# Calculating symplectic dual of a code

Tags: quantum-algorithms, error-correction, clifford-group

Stabilizer codes can be treated as symplectic codes over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (or over $\mathbb{F}_p$ when taking about q-dits). While treating error class, symplectic dual of the code plays a crucial part (Normlizer of the stabilizer if we wish to talk in group theoretic terms).
For classical hamming codes, given a code in either parity check form or generator matrix form, it is quiet easy to calculate corresponding forms for the dual.
Is there an efficient (preferably classical) algorithm to compute this for symplectic code?